# Connect to vagrant through a gradle task

Tags: gradle, vagrant

I am relatively new to gradle and I want is to create a gradle task that will run and connect to "vagrant ssh".  It seems that running an interactive shell though gradle is not possible.

I have used both the Exec plugin and also another approach to spawn "vagrant ssh" through expectJ and then use the "interact()" method but none of them was working.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on the [gradle-vagrant plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-vagrant-plugin)

The plugin has specific [task](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-vagrant-plugin#custom-task-types) to handle vagrantX command (such as vagrant up/ssh ...)

see for example how you can run a command directly from gradle script

```
vagrant {
    boxDir = file('~/dev/my-vagrant-box')

    environmentVariables {
        variable 'IP', '192.168.1.33'
        variable 'OPERATINGSYSTEM', 'redhat'
    }

    installation {
        validate = false
    }
}

import com.bmuschko.gradle.vagrant.tasks.Vagrant
import com.bmuschko.gradle.vagrant.tasks.VagrantSsh

task vagrantListsBoxes(type: Vagrant) {
    description = 'Outputs a list of available Vagrant boxes.'
    commands = ['box', 'list']
}

task vagrantEcho(type: VagrantSsh) {
    description = 'Runs remote SSH command in Vagrant box.'
    sshCommand = "echo 'hello'"

    dependsOn vagrantUp
    finalizedBy vagrantDestroy
}
```

Comment: Henri: I have already checked this.  "VagrantSsh" is just to issue some commands to the vagrant box. What I need is to connect to the vagrant shell and give there any command i want manually. Hence I need a way to connect to the shell through gradle in interactive mode.